# jBPM simple work item - ioSpecification is not complete error

Tags: jbpm

i am trying to do simple work item from here: http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.4/userguide/ch.domain-specific-processes.html#d0e7389
my code:

.wid file

```
import org.drools.process.core.datatype.impl.type.StringDataType;
[
  // the Notification work item
  [
    "name" : "Notification",
    "parameters" : [
      "Message" : new StringDataType(),
      "From" : new StringDataType(),
      "To" : new StringDataType(),
      "Priority" : new StringDataType(),
    ],
    "displayName" : "Notification",
    "icon" : "icons/notification.gif"
  ]
]
```

then i implemented and registered work item handler with simple

```
@Override
public void executeWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemManager manager) {
    String from = (String) workItem.getParameter("From");
    System.out.println("from " + from);
}
```

my custom node automatically appeared in eclipse modeler, so i made simple process:
 start > node > end
and set value of 'From' parameter, but when executing it i get:

```
ERROR ExtensibleXmlParser:666 - (null: 24, 31): cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'bpmn2:ioSpecification' is not complete. One of '{"http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL":inputSet, "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL":outputSet}' is expected.
```

**also 'from null' is printed**

my bpmn file contains only one ioSpecification, and it have inputSet node

```
  <bpmn2:ioSpecification id="_InputOutputSpecification_12">
    <bpmn2:dataInput id="_DataInput_15" name="Message"/>
    <bpmn2:dataInput id="_DataInput_16" itemSubjectRef="ItemDefinition_4" name="From"/>
    <bpmn2:dataInput id="_DataInput_17" name="To"/>
    <bpmn2:dataInput id="_DataInput_18" name="Priority"/>
    <bpmn2:inputSet id="_InputSet_12" name="Input Set 12">
      <bpmn2:dataInputRefs>_DataInput_15</bpmn2:dataInputRefs>
      <bpmn2:dataInputRefs>_DataInput_16</bpmn2:dataInputRefs>
      <bpmn2:dataInputRefs>_DataInput_17</bpmn2:dataInputRefs>
      <bpmn2:dataInputRefs>_DataInput_18</bpmn2:dataInputRefs>
    </bpmn2:inputSet>
  </bpmn2:ioSpecification>
```

i am using jbpm 5.4.final
eclipse BPMN2 Editor 0.2.5.201305082126
eclipse JBoss jBPM5 Runtime Extension Feature   0.2.5.201305082126
eclipse  JBoss jBPM Core    5.5.0.Final
eclipse  JBoss jBPM Task    5.5.0.Final

Answer (score 1):

ioSpecification always requires an outputSet (as defined in the XSD), but this might be empty.